# Wordpress Update CustomFields Section after updating custom field with AJAX call

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a question regarding the CustomFields section in Wordpress when adding a new post. I have a plugin that adds a meta_box to the edit/new page of a post. Inside this meta_box, I have a button that, when pressed, uses an AJAX call to update/add custom field values to the new post.

This all works fine, however the custom field section is, logically, not updated to reflect this newly added value. I want to refresh the custom field section of the edit page for this new post to update/reload to reflect the current values..

[image]

Does anyone know if and how this should be done in Wordpress?

TIA,
John

Comment: Which plugin are you using? If you need a specific use case It could be good to do a custom plugin yourself that does what you need.

Comment: I am writing a plugin, I want to refresh the custom field section when I press a button in my custom plugin..

Comment: Use wp-ajax : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: that is what I am doing, I post data using AJAX in my metabox.. then upon return I want to refresh the custom field section.. let me explain in a screenshot